# Postgresql 13. Вывод названия месяца на Русском (to_char)

Tags: postgresql, datetime, locale

Подскажите. пожалуйста, стандартный способ в psql для того чтобы можно было получить название месяца на русском языке.
`SELECT to_char(TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 20:38:40', 'Month YYYY').`
Кодировка на все : *Russian_Russia.1251*
TimeZone: Европа/Москва.
Postgresql:13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если локаль серверу известна, то (обрати внимание на `TM` перед `Month`)

```
set lc_time = 'ru_RU';
select to_char(now(), 'TMMonth')
```

Если неизвестно, то, наверное, никак.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!